# VB.NET - Multiple SQLDataReader's

Tags: vb.net

I develop a lot in ASP.NET and I know that you can only open one SQLDataReader for each SQLConnection.  However, this does not appear to be the case in VB.NET (form application) i.e. I have opened multiple SQLDataReaders for one connection object.  Is this allowed in VB.NET?

If there is not an obvious answer to this then I will post some code.

Here is some code:

```
Public Function CheckActiveReviews()
            Dim objCon As SqlConnection
            Dim objCommand As SqlCommand, objCommand2 As SqlCommand
            Dim objDR As SqlDataReader, objDR2 As SqlDataReader
            Try
                objCon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=TestDatabase;Initial Catalog=TestTable;User ID=TestUser;Password=TestPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
                objCommand = New SqlCommand
                objCommand.Connection = objCon
                objCommand2 = New SqlCommand
                objCommand2.Connection = objCon
                objCon.Open()
                objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ID FROM Person WHERE PersonID > 1000"
                objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader()
                Do While objDR.Read
                    objCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Sport WHERE PersonID = @PersonID "
                    objCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonID", objDR("ID"))
                    objDR2 = objCommand2.ExecuteReader
                Loop

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End Function
```

Comment: For performance, use Stored Procedures rather than Ad-Hoc queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use multiple data readers if you use [MARS - Multiple Active Result Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - but I wouldn't advise that unless you really need it.

Instead, I'd suggest creating a new `SqlConnection` object each time you need it - use it for as short a period as you can, then dispose of it (use a `Using` statement to do this for you). The connection pool will take care of the efficiency in terms of reusing "physical" network connections where possible. That way you don't need to worry about whether the `SqlConnection` is already open etc - you just always follow the same "create, open, use, dispose" pattern every time.

Comment: Thanks.  If you have a SQL statement in a WHILE loop then I don't think your pattern above will work? Are you able to confirm if this is the case?

Comment: @w0051977: Why wouldn't it work? If you're using the connection in a while loop then it's fine to use one connection for that whole block - it *would* work if you created a new connection on each iteration, but it would be slightly pointless. (You should close each *command*, mind you.) Basically it's hard to know whether or not something would work without more specifics, but it's entirely possible to execute SQL in a loop.

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  When you say "create a new connection on every loop" are you referring to shadowing?

Comment: @w0051977: I never said that, so it's hard to know what you mean. Present *actual code* (e.g. in the question) and we can discuss that. I'm certainly not talking about shadowing of variables though.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have put some code in the question. Could you take a look?

Comment: @w0051977: Okay, so it's not really the looping that's the issue there - it's using the same connection for two commands at the same time. I'd try to avoid doing that - create two connections instead. I'd also use `Using` statement to ensure you dispose of everything, and avoid catching exceptions and just swallowing them.

Comment: Finally, could you explain why it is advised to avoid using two commands at the same time?

Comment: @w0051977: Using two commands *on the same connection* requires MARS, whereas there's no indication that you really *need* that here. Just use two connections, and it's simpler.